# Why is my code causing an infinite loop?

Tags: java, infinite-loop

I'm currently working on a method which creates a playlist from a music library. The idea is that it asks for a minimum rating for songs and a minimum runtime for the playlist and then produces a random list of songs which fit those criteria. If there are not enough songs of the minimum rating, it reduces the rating by 1 and then looks for songs which meet that requirement. (So if you specified that the playlist should have 60 mins of 5 star songs, but you don't have enough, it tries to fill the rest of the time with 4 star songs instead.)

However, if my library contains no 5 star songs, an infinite loop is caused in my code. (Or I assume so, anyway, the test program doesn't stop running) Why could this be?

```
public Playlist createPlaylist(int minRating, int minDuration) {
        minDuration = minDuration * 60;              
        ArrayList<Track> shuffledList = trackList;
        Playlist playlist = new Playlist();
        Collections.shuffle(shuffledList);
        int playlistDuration = 0;
        while (playlistDuration <= minDuration) {
            for (Track track : shuffledList) {
                if (track.getRating() >= minRating && !playlist.contains(track)) 
                {
                    playlist.add(track);
                    playlistDuration += track.getLength();
                }
                if (playlistDuration >= minDuration) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            minRating--;
        }
        playlist.randomise();
        return playlist;
```

Comment: Seems like 'playlistDuration' is not updated which means that this part: if (track.getRating() >= minRating && !playlist.contains(track)) is never true.

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to figure out; put some debug print statements in, or step through the code in a debugger.

Comment: It works when I have 5-star rating tracks though.

Comment: If you don't have enough tracks then the playlistDuration will never go up and will always be smaller than minDuration.

Comment: may be the track.getLength() always 0, you need to debug it step by step

Comment: if your minRating goes below 5, you want to break the loop? In that case simply add the condition to `while(...)`

Comment: You also have an ambiguous state.  You want to continue to loop if `playlistDuration <= minDuration` and break if `playlistDuration >= minDuration`. So, think about what happens when `playlistDuration == minDuration`. Who wins?

Comment: +1 for new(ish) user with a well written question

Comment: Ahhhh, great solve,  @hfontanez. You got it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `playlistDuration` is updated conditionally, there could be many reasons for the loop to become infinite. For example, if `shuffledList` is empty, your `playlistDuration` would remain zero, so the outer loop would be infinite.

You can avoid this if you adjust `minDuration` to the total duration of `shuffledList` before entering the loop:

```
minDuration = Math.Min(minDuration, shuffledList.Sum(t => t.getLength()));
```

In plain English this means "I cannot ask for a minimum duration of more than the total duration of `shuffledList`".

You should also change the condition of your `while` loop to strict "less than", because otherwise the infinite loop would remain when `shuffledList` is empty.

```
while (playlistDuration < minDuration) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it is possible to go through the body of the `while` loop without changing `playlistDuration`; in particular, when you don't add any tracks.

Answer (score 1):

Change your loop like this, exit the loop when all tracks have been browsed and rating == -1

```
while (playlistDuration <= minDuration) {
    for (Track track : shuffledList) {
        if (track.getRating() >= minRating && !playlist.contains(track)) 
        {
            playlist.add(track);
            playlistDuration += track.getLength();
        }
        if (playlistDuration > minDuration) {
            break;
        }
    }
    minRating--;
    if (minRating == -1) break;
}
```

Comment: I would change `if (playlistDuration >= minDuration)` to `if (playlistDuration > minDuration)`

Comment: Yes, it makes sense with the global while condition

Comment: The equality comparison must be removed from the `while` or from the `if`. Can't be on both.  It is illogical to say loop while equal and by the way, break if equal.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't finding any 5-star songs, you don't update `playlistDuration`, so your while loop goes on forever.

Answer (score 0):

what happens when there are not enough tracks to get playlistDuration > minDuration?

My guess is:

```
while( playListDuration <= minDuration )
```

trudges on.

Thus, you might want to check for that in your while, one option would be to add condition that tracks exist

PS: wow. While typing a couple of lines, 3 answers posted, downvote, upvote. Sheesh.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems

(1) If the total duration of the songs is too small, it will never exit. You need an exit condition based on min rating. Since the iterator over the shuffled list is always finite, this will guarantee that the code exits.

(2) The equalities don't seem to match up. If its min duration == playlist duration, it continues iterating even though it doesnt add any tracks, which is wasteful. Change the while loop to strictly less than.

(3) It would be much more efficient if you sorted the list by rating using a treeSet with a custom comparator. then you would only have to iterate over the list of tracks once.